# What is the meaning of 까 in the song Gangnam Style?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-usage

"*Gangnam style*" is a famous Korean song. At a certain point, the lyrics go:

> 지금부터 갈데까지 가볼 까?
>
> Jigeum buteo gal-de-kkaji gabol kka?

I have managed to analyse this as follows:

- Jigeum means "now";
- Buteo means "from(...on)";
- Gal is the future adnominal form of gada, "to go"; such a form is used in relative clauses for "...who will go", but also in combination with de-kkaji to indicate action extent;
- Gabol is ga-, root of gada again, with bol, future adnominal of try;

So the sentence should mean roughly "From now on (jigeum buteo) for how long (action extent) will we continue trying to go forward?". So the question is:

> Is the above analysis correct? Is the translation right? What is the function of 까 in this sentence?

(PS Shouldn't we have a [translation](/questions/tagged/translation) and a [word-usage](/questions/tagged/word-usage) tag?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct spelling is 지금부터 갈 데까지 가 볼까?

-까 is mostly some kind of deliberation or suggestion. The example roughly translates to,
"Shall we try and go all the way from now on?" or "Do you want to try going all the way from now on?"

A note: strictly translating -보다 to "try" can often be a bit too much, it's just a way to make a suggestion sound more gentle. I guess a close but more natural English translation would be, "Do you wanna go all the way from here?"

지금부터 - from now (on)
갈 데까지 - until the point where we can/will go ~ until the end, all the way
가 - go
가 볼까? - shall we try going? or simply, shall we go?

Comment: I guess you meant "all the way from now on" in the second rough translation, which as of now has no "way".

Comment: Yes! I already edited that a few minutes ago, maybe it didn't update yet.

Comment: I prpbably last reloaded before the edit :).

Comment: I believe this is 갈 때까지, not 갈 데까지

Comment: @dotVezz You might be right. I navered for 강남 스타일 가사 and while most sites quote it as 갈 데까지, Naver Music also has 갈 때까지 http://music.naver.com/lyric/index.nhn?trackId=3264116

Comment: Here they say both is possible, in principle: http://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=61&qna_seq=15187
So as long as we don't have an "official" source for the lyrics, it's hard to judge.

Comment: @user12 @dotVezz @파울울 It's not hard to judge **at all**. [Stick with `갈 데까지 가다`.](https://korean.stackexchange.com/questions/3398/which-one-is-correct-갈-데까지-가다-or-갈-때까지-가다)

Comment: You're right, the proper idiom is 갈 데까지 가다. The linked source does say that "갈 때까지" is also grammatical, but unlikely that is what is meant here.

Answer (score 2):

~까 is used to make a sentence in a form of question, NOT to ask, but to express/imply suggestion, intention, a little doubt (not complete assurance of the speaker's intention), try, etc.

e.g.)  비가 온다는데 집에 있어야겠다. (I heard it's going to rain, so I will stay home)
whereas

비가 온다는데 집에 있어볼까? (I heard it's going to rain, maybe I'd better stay home / I may stay home)

날씨가 좋으니 바닷가에 가자. The weather is great, let's go to the beach.

날씨가 좋은데 우리 바닷가에 가볼까? The weather is great. Shall we go to the beach?

Answer (score 1):

A 부터 B 까지 means from A to B

A and B may be actual places or may represent something more abstract like events

서울부터 부산까지 ( from place A to place B)

시작부터 끝까지 (from event A to event B)

[This video](https://youtu.be/5Y3HzOrphNY?t=445) has a line by line translation and a basic explanation of the whole song

Answer (score 0):

I am confused with the word 식기도 I have googled it's meaning and it seems it can mean tableware, cooking, dishes, but 강남 스타일 uses it to mean, 'Man hitting one shot before the coffee is cold''커피 식기도 전에 원샷 때리는 사나이'.

Comment: I believe you want to analyse that as 식기, from 식다 "cool down", plus 도 "even", which, paired with 전에 "before", would make 식기도 전에 "before [it] even gets cold". At this point I'd say 원샷 때리다 is a compound verb meaning just "one-shot", and the line would say "a man who one-shots [his] coffee before [it] even gets cold".

Comment: @Kurt Grieve if you have a question please ask it as a separate question

Comment: Thank you both, greatly appreciated