# Which one is correct: ‘갈 데까지 가다’ or ‘갈 때까지 가다’?

Tags: pronunciation, meaning, difference, idiom

*PSY*'s [<강남 스타일 (Gangnam style)>](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9bZkp7q19f0). It's kind of famous, you know. This is what its lyrics say:

> 지금부터 **갈 데까지 가** 볼까?
>
> Shall we **go all the way through** from now on?

But is it really `데` here? Isn't it `때`? It sounds more like `때` somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an idiomatic expression and **the correct one is ‘`갈 데까지 가다`’.** The other one does not make any sense. Their pronunciation is similar, though.

---

## Their meanings

- [`갈 데까지 가다`](http://www.korean.go.kr/front/onlineQna/onlineQnaView.do?mn_id=61&qna_seq=15187) [갈**떼**까지가다] (`갈`<sub>(one goes)</sub> `데`<sub>(where)</sub> `-까지`<sub>(up to)</sub> `가다`<sub>(to go)</sub>) literally means ‘`to go far as one goes (one may go)`’.

  > 1. 도달할 수 있는 가장 극단의 상태나 상황이 되다.
  >      To fall into the most extreme state or situation possible.
  >
  >    - Eg. `어디 누가 이기는지 갈 데까지 가 보자.` `Let's go to extremes (keep doing this) to see who'll be the final winner.`
  > 2. 성관계를 맺다. To go all the way; to have sex.
  >
  >    - Eg. `그녀와 나는 갈 데까지 간 사이다.` `I went all the way with her.`
- `갈 때까지 가다` [갈**때**까지가다] (`갈`<sub>(one goes)</sub> `때`<sub>(when)</sub> `-까지`<sub>(up to)</sub> `가다`<sub>(to go)</sub>) literally means ‘`to go (to keep going) until one goes`’. I have never used this phrase even once.

---

## Why does the `데` sound [떼] here?

You know, I just got this naturally, following others' Korean;
if you're not a native, here's the standard for you.

> ## [표준어 규정 제2부<sub>(표준 발음법)</sub> 제6장<sub>(경음화)</sub>](http://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000102) 제27항
>
> ## [*Korean Language Standard* chapter #2 <sub>(Standard pronunciation)</sub>, section §6 <sub>(Tensification)</sub>](http://www.korean.go.kr/front/page/pageView.do?page_id=P000102), clause #27:
>
> 관형사형 ‘`-(으)ㄹ`’ 뒤에 연결되는 ‘`ㄱ`, `ㄷ`, `ㅂ`, `ㅅ`, `ㅈ`’은 된소리로 발음한다.
>
> ‘`ㄱ`’, ‘`ㄷ`’, ‘`ㅂ`’, ‘`ㅅ`’, and ‘`ㅈ`’ following endings ‘`-ㄹ`’ or ‘`-을`’ that make things 관형사 (Korean pre-nouns; similar to *determiners*.), are *tensified* (become 된소리).
>
> - `할 것을` [할꺼슬] (`ㄱ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - **`갈 데가` [갈떼가] (`ㄷ` following `-ㄹ`)**
> - `할 바를` [할빠를] (`ㅂ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - `할 수는` [할쑤는] (`ㅅ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - `먹을 수는` [머글쑤는] (`ㅅ` following `-을`)
> - `할 적에` [할쩌게] (`ㅈ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - `갈 곳` [갈꼳] (`ㄱ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - `할 도리` [할또리] (`ㄷ` following `-ㄹ`)
> - `만날 사람` [만날싸람] (`ㅅ` following `-ㄹ`)